# Macro for interactive map in excel - shading process

Tags: vba, excel, shading

I've made a map (by looking through some guides) of the world for Excel that color-codes countries based on values entered in cells.
I don't understand why an error message pops up for this code, stating that the name used doesn't quite exist.

Here's the code :

```
Sub Shading()

    For i = 3 To 79
    Range("actReg").Value = Range("ShadingMacro!A" & i).Value
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Range("actReg").Value).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Range("actRegCode").Value).Interior.Color

    Next i

    Range("A21").Select[enter image description here][1]

End Sub
```

And here's the error message (sorry it is in French) :

> Erreur d'exécution '-2147024809 (80070057)':
>   L'élément portant ce nom est introuvable

Then the "débogage" tool brings me to the 3rd line :

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Range("actReg").Value).Select
```

But I don't quite understand where the problem is.

Comment: Can you translate the error message to English?  I see you can speak English pretty well since the rest of the post is in English.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: When it crashes, look at your "actReg" range and verify that the value in that cell is the name of one of your shapes.

Comment: @TimHutchison - Sorry - it looks like my edit collided with your edit.  I think I made all the changes you were trying to make anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
I realised yesterday that this error indeed came from the discrepancy between my "actReg" range and the name of the shape so I corrected it. Unfortunately it does not work yet, I have a new message error for the next line of code : "Execution error '1004' : the 'Range' method of the '_Global' object has failed" (or something like that because I translated the french error message as you asked @TimHutchison)
Hoping you have the answer for that too, thanks anyway for your help !!